# Page not redirect to any other page during download

Tags: php, redirect, download

I have a web page in which there is a option to download file. Download is fine but during downloading, page is not redirecting to another till the download completed.

The code I used to download a file is below:

```
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=NRI legal services_".$row['document_path']);
header("Expires: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", mktime(date("H")+2, date("i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d"), date("Y")))." GMT");
header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")." GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');

header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

readfile($file);
```

Please help to sort it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know how a web page can know when a particular download is finished. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding you...

Comment: @Mike: Can download affects bandwidth? May it affects bandwidth and that is the reason of all this.

Comment: *"page is not redirecting to another till the download completed."* - Then it works and is doing its job.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to make a wrapper page, like 01net, that has a link to the download link (in your case the php file above), then redirects to a thank you page using javascript. You can't do it the way you are trying to do.